# Is it possible to generate a .lib file on windows using clang-cl?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang, clang-cl

I am on Windows and I have Visual Studio installed and the latest version of `clang`. I am able to run:

```
clang-cl hello.c
```

Which in turn generates `hello.exe`, which I can run as expected.

But what I want to do is to generate a static library instead (`.lib` file). I am able to pass the `/LD` flag to generate a dynamic link library but I can't figure out how to generate a static library instead.

Is this possible to do with `clang-cl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it seems to be possible.

Use `-fuse-ld=llvm-lib` to link multiple source files into a static library

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the answer is to use `llvm-lib`. This threw me off a bit because it wasn't named `clang-lib` but it appears to be doing what I am expecting.